# Media Item upload upload size validation - confirm dialog issue

Tags: sitecore-client, media-library

I am trying to validate media item whilst uploading to check if the media of certain type has a specific size limit. Created a pipeline which replaces the Sitecore.Pipelines.Upload.CheckSize to the custom pipeline.

If file is not valid i.e. within the Size limit args error text is set as below-

```
args.UiResponseHandler.FileTooBig(StringUtil.EscapeJavascriptString(fileName));
args.ErrorText = $"The  file {fileName} is too big to be uploaded. Testing testing The maximum size for uploading files is {limit} MB.";
args.AbortPipeline();
```

When I try uploading multiple files I am able to see the above custom message, but whilst uploading a single file I see the message which is set in Sitecore.Pipelines.Upload.CheckSize class i.e. instead of custom message I see this-

[image]

the same file uploaded using (advanced) option

[image]

Has anybody faced this issue, help here is appreciated.

Comment: Can you share your code for us to be able to provide a solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Upload file` and `Upload files (advanced)` use different methods for communication between the frontend and backend for the alerts that are shown.

The advanced upload will display whatever you set in `args.ErrorText` but Upload files through a slightly roundabout way calls `ShowFileTooBig(string filename)` in `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Media.UploadMedia.UploadMediaForm`.

Provide a new implmentation of the `ShowFileTooBig` method and add in the same validation as you do in your pipeline and show the correct message:

```cs
public class UploadMediaForm : Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Media.UploadMedia.UploadMediaForm
{
  private string ErrorMessage  = "The image \"{0}\" is too big to be uploaded. The maximum size for uploading images is {1}.";

  protected new void ShowFileTooBig(string filename)
  {
    string extension = Path.GetExtension(filename);
    if (!extension.Equals(".jpg"))
    {
      base.ShowFileTooBig(filename);
      return;
    }

    SheerResponse.Alert(Translate.Text(ErrorMessage, filename, MainUtil.FormatSize(ImageSettings.MaxImageSizeInDatabase)));
    this.OK.Disabled = true;
    this.Cancel.Disabled = true;
    this.OK.Disabled = false;
    this.Cancel.Disabled = false;
  }
}
```

Create a copy of */sitecore/shell/Applications/Media/Upload Media/UploadMedia.xml* and place it in */sitecore/shell/Override*. Edit the file and update the type specified in the `CodeBeside` tag to your own implementation. We need to provide a new implementation of the `ShowFileTooBig` method.

I've made an assumption that you have a custom `uiUpload` pipeline processor that checks the file being uploaded and returns the error. You can find a [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/jammykam/9dba9bfd321df6b49e0091bda2343163) with a fuller code example but the above should answer your specific question.

Note that your question only deals with the [simple HTML version of the uploader](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/8894/135). You also need to deal with the Flash enabled uploader. This requires further updates similar to [this StackOverflow answer I previosuly provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27956033/661447).

Comment: Thanks Jammy. The above solution solved the issue. Only that I changed the implementation  of ImageCheckSize for attaching media to have a custom message.https://gist.github.com/sandeepvpote/5ae257440eab2a6a0f06da4be0f58548

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may need to override parts of `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Media.UploadMedia.UploadMediaForm, Sitecore.Client` and customize `UploadMedia.xml`. There is a check for the `OnLoad` method of `UploadMediaPage2` which does a response write that ends up calling the method `ShowFileTooBig`. This will allow you to show your custom message but unfortunately I am not sure if the file will still be blocked from being uploaded if it qualified as too big for the check in `ClientPage`. Based on what I'm seeing I think it won't upload the file so if your desire is just to inject a custom message going this route should be fine. If you actually want to change what the `ClientPage` base class marks as a request that is too big then something else will be needed.

Comment: Thank Teeknow for pointing to the right direction on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below answer.
It will work on both Upload File and Upload Files(Advance)

```
 public void Process(UploadArgs args)
    {
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object)args, "args");
        if (args.Destination == UploadDestination.File)
            return;
        foreach (string index in args.Files)
        {
        // If you are uploading zip file then you have to write your own logic get the file details form the zip.
            HttpPostedFile file = args.Files[index];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(file.FileName) && IsRestrictedExtension(file.FileName))
            {
                if (((long)file.ContentLength / 1024f) / 1024 > 2)//checking file size as 2MB or not
                {
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<html><head><script type=\"text/JavaScript\" language=\"javascript\">alert('Its worked');</script></head><body>Done</body></html>");
                    args.AbortPipeline();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```